# Why is skimage.transform.rotate significantly slower than PIL's Image.rotate?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm in the process of converting some PIL-based code over to NumPy, but I've found that the [`skimage.transform.rotate`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#rotate) function is *significantly* slower than PIL's `Image.rotate`.

As a rough comparison, using `skimage`'s rotate on a ~1000x1000 pixel image takes ~2.2 seconds, while `Image.rotate` takes ~0.1 seconds:

```
import time
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rotate

im = Image.open("some_big_image.png").convert("L")
print "Image size: %s" %(im.size, )

s = time.time()
im.rotate(10, Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
print "Image.rotate: %0.04f" %(time.time() - s, )

ima = np.array(im) / 255.0
s = time.time()
rotate(ima, 10, order=3) # order=3 --> bi-cubic filtering
print "skimage.transform.rotate: %0.04f" %(time.time() - s, )
```

And the output:

```
$ py rotate.py
Image size: (1275, 1650)
Image.rotate: 0.1154
skimage.transform.rotate: 2.2310
```

(these numbers are more or less consistent across multiple runs; I don't believe that this is an artifact of not running enough tests)

So! What's up with that? Is there any way to speed up skimage's `rotate`?

Version info:

- PIL: 1.1.7
- skimage: 0.14.1
- numpy: 1.7.1
- Python: 2.7.2

It may also be worth noting:

- If `BICUBIC` filtering isn't used, the `im.rotate` operation only takes ~0.01 seconds, while setting `order=0` to use nearest-neighbour filtering, `skimage.rotate` takes ~0.6 seconds.

Comment: how many runs did you do to compare the times?

Comment: I've noticed this behavior across ~100 runs. There is a ~10% variation between runs (as you would expect), but nothing that could explain the 20x time difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the latest version from https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image. Just a few days ago I fixed a bug (see https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/commit/d5776656a8217e58cb28d5760439a54e96d15316) related to this slow down.

My numbers are as follows with the current dev version:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rotate

a = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=np.uint8)

im = Image.fromarray(a)

%timeit im.rotate(10, Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)

ima = a / 255.0
%timeit rotate(ima, 10, order=1)
%timeit rotate(ima, 10, order=3)


## -- Output --
10 loops, best of 3: 41.3 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 43.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Interestingly, the times are a bit more disparate on my machine: 50ms/loop with PIL, but 160ms/loop with sk-image… but, for now, this should be fast enough for my purposes.

Comment: Probably related to the compiler you use. I'm using LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) and -O3.

Comment: Ah, ya, probably. I'm major version below you: `Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`

Answer (score 1):

Having only read the Python code and not the Cython code for `warp()`, guess would be that since skimage is using generic warping code, its code paths are less efficient than something written specifically to do in-plane rotation and nothing else.